# Insert variable in Dictionary Python

Tags: python

I need to insert two variables in my python dictionary

I get values ​​by a get function, and assign value to my variable as below:

```
FirstDate = request.POST.get('DataInicial')
LastDate = request.POST.get('DataFinal')
```

I need to use the value of these two variables inside a dictionary, which will be a value that will be passed to an API

```
body = {"inicio" : "**{FirstDate}** 00:00:01", "fim" : "**{LastDate}** 23:59:59"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```py
body = {"inicio" : "**%s** 00:00:01" % FirstDate, "fim" : "**%s** 23:59:59" % LastDate}
```

See [Python string formatting](https://pyformat.info/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the format string literal if you are using python 3.6+. This will replace any variables inside curly braces with the value of that variable. You can read about it [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

```py
body = {"inicio": f"**{FirstDate}** 00:00:01", "fim": f"**{LastDate}** 23:59:59"}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `str.format` method for version of python before 3.6. You can read about that [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

```py
body = {"inicio": "**{}** 00:00:01".format(FirstDate), 
        "fim":    "**{}** 23:59:59".format(LastDate)}
```